# Searching for multiple values in exact order in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm looking for a way to do an exact array match in which the items must be in order.

example documents:

```
{"id": 1, "categories" : ["A", "C","E"]}
{"id": 2, "categories" : ["A", "C"]}
{"id": 3, "categories" : ["C", "A"]}
```

When I search with "A" AND "C", it will only return the first and third documents

```
{"id": 1, "categories" : ["A", "C","E"]}
{"id": 2, "categories" : ["A", "C"]}
```

The third one shouldn't be returned because the order doesn't match.

I have tried the following query but it will still return the third document because it doesn't take order in consideration:

```
{
    "sort": [
      {
        "modified": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "categories": "A"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "categories": "C"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have more than 50 fields that I want to provide this exact order search option, so I prefer not adding extra field serving as a categories keyword and querying with "AC",
{"id": 1, "categories" : ["c", "d"], "categorieskey" : "cd"}

is there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: categories there is not an array data type, but rather a multi-value field, also, there is no explicit order of these values, so you need to really rethink your problem

Comment: Probably the best way would be to store these in a lowercased string value and compare to it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add that `categorieskey` field because:

- this should give the best performance when it comes to searching. Just matching an exact value in a field (basically a `term` filter, nothing complex)
- I don't think there is an easy way for this. Even if you wouldn't use `categorieskey` Elasticsearch has no way in knowing the order of those terms. And to perform a search/filter on the `_source` is painful, uses many resources and the searches will not be fast at all

All in all, go ahead an add that field, this is the best approach in my opinion.